# Setting a string's last state before it changes to use it later on

Tags: java, android, arrays

Sorry if I can't explain my problem properly, I'm running on caffeine right now.

Basically there is the string "written" which the application writes to declare certain states to the user.

```
String written = textview.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
```

Written works properly.

But "written" changes on a regular basis, and I'd like to record past instances of "written" in an array named "writtenPast"

I have tried arraylist but didn't succeed.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
public void onClick(View v){

String written = textview.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

if(edittext.equals("something"){
testview.setText(result1);

}

if(edittext.equals("somethingelse"){
textview.setText(result2);
}
```

I want to be able to access, for example, the last instance of written before it was changed.

Let's say it's result2 right now and it was result1 before.

I want to be able to access result1.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<String> pastWrittenStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Use above list to store the past written data, and in `onClick(View v){`

```
pastWrittenStrings.add(written); // save to the list before it gets modified
written = textview.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
```

to get the latest written, before it got modified

```
if(!pastWrittenStrings.isEmpty()) {
   pastWrittenStrings.get(pastWrittenStrings.size()-1); // the last entry would be the latest written just before it got modified
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String written = "";
String prevWritten = "";

public void onClick(View v){

   prevWritten = written;
   written = textview.getText().toLowerCase();

   if(prevWritten.isEmpty()){
      prevWritten = written;
   }

   ..other code..
}
```

**Edit:** Based from the comment using a list-

```
List<String> writtens = new ArrayList<String>();


public void onClick(View v){

    writtens.add(textview.getText().toLowerCase());

    /* 
        To get first written: writtens.get(0);
        To get last written: writtens.get(writtens.size() - 1);
        To get in a random postion: writtens.get(indexNumber);

    */

}
```

But it's better if you don't save tons of strings. Rather have a max number of strings you would like to store. Say if you want to store a maximum of 10 strings, when the size of the writtens is already 10, store the next one at index 0.

Comment: this is a nice answer but i need more than one instance of written's previous states.

Comment: Then you need a list or array to store the strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the event before the text is changed using a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html), and you can save the past written values in a `List` of `CharSequence` Objects.

So something like this would work best:

```
List<CharSequence> writtenPast = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);//or whatever
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 

    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { 
        if (!writtenPast.contains(s)) {
            writtenPast.add(s);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

This approach, however, may get you some unwanted results, and some more filtering may be required. If you are instead handling past written Strings every time a button is clicked, you can still use the relevant code above. For example:

```
List<CharSequence> writtenPast = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);//or whatever
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == edittext) {
        if (!writtenPast.contains(edittext.getText())) {
            writtenPast.add(edittext.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest a TextWatcher. Oh, and to not write code when you are obviously fatigued, haha.

Answer (score 0):

You should identify an event when that text change happen and you can use ArrayList to add text in that text field in each time